# Form not passing value on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling with getting my results from an API to show up on HTML page. Does work if the function is executed in the console.

```
<body>
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter person">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="fetchPerson()" />
      </form>
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

JS:

```
    function fetchPerson() {
    var input = document.getElementById('search').value;
    fetch(`notrevealingapi/api/name=${input}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const html = data.data
            .map(hit => {
                return `<p>Hits: ${hit.person}</p>`;
            })
            .join("");
        document.querySelector('#app').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    })
    
}
```

Comment: You did nothing to prevent the normal form submission, so this will load a "new page", and anything you just tried to do via JavaScript on the current page, will get discarded.

Comment: You don't really need a `<form>` at all. Your "submit" input could be a `<button type=button>`.

Comment: Okay thanks guys, that did the trick! New to this so didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly.
you want to populate the result in the `<div id="app">` when a user clicks on the `submit` button.
There is two basic mistakes I can think of.

1. You should use the `button` type instead of `submit`
2. And use `innerHTML` instead of the `insertAdjacentHTML`. So it would look like

```
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = html
```